# does git ls-files print files in the current working directory

Tags: git

I was told that `git ls-files` print files in the current working directory. Let's say I have a directory called MyFolder, then I created a new file `HelloWorld.cs`(and I did't use `git add` to add this file), then I run `git ls-files` and it didn't display `HelloWorld.cs`. But technically speaking, `HelloWorld.cs` is in the current working directory(MyFolder), so why it didn't get displayed?

Answer (score 1):

`git ls-files` can print a variety of things.  By default, and with the `-c` option, it prints the files in the index.  Since you didn't use `git add` to add the file to the index, it's untracked, and it's not printed by default.

If you want to print all the untracked files, you can run `git ls-files -o` to see the untracked files, or `git ls-files -co` to print both the files in the index and the untracked files.  `git ls-files --help` will show you all the possible options.

If you just want to to print the files in your working tree, you can use `find . -name '.git' -prune -o -print`.  To print just the files in the current directory, use `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name '.git' -prune -o -type f -print`.

Comment: The answer regarding printing files in the working tree is somewhat OK but does not follow ".gitignore" patterns which might be one reason one would use "git ls-files" over a simple "find"